# How to check if a map contain a empty string value in scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a newbie question.

We can use `contains` to check if a map contain a specified key, as:

```
val map = Map("a"->"1", "b"->"")
map.contains("a")
```

But now, I want to check if the map contains an empty string, is there any method to use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
map.values.exists(_ == "")
```

---

Edit: I think the above is the clearest, but I can't resist showing two others.

```
map.exists(_._2 == "")
```

is more compact, but you have to remember that _2 is the value when you iterate through a map.

```
map.values.exists(""==)
```

is an alternative form of the original, where instead of explicitly comparing the argument with `_ == ""`, you supply an equality function `"".equals _` or `""==` for short.  (Two ways of looking at the same thing--is it the empty string supplying its equals method for testing, or is it your closure testing the elements against the empty string?  I think the latter (the original) is considerably clearer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
map.values.toSet.contains("")
```

or:

```
map find { case (a,b) => b == "" } isDefined
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can just write:

```
map contains ""
```

Comment: This is wrong. He wants to check if the map contains a value with the value `""`. Not the key as you proposed.